# Order 2 columns by matching to another column

Tags: vba, excel, spreadsheet

I have 4 columns in an excel file:
[image]

The two on the right have about 9000 rows, the 2 on the left have about 14000.
Column A and B are connected. Also, C & D are connected.

The THER_CLASS column is the 1st 6 numbers of the key column.

How would I order the left two columns by if the 1st 6 of the key matches THER_CLASS?
I want each row to take the A column find which row the 1st 6 # of GPI are equal and then move C and D to the row that A is on.

I could do this by building a console app in c# but I feel like there is a way to to it much easier in excel.

Comment: Could you maybe add a small example of the output, you want to achieve?

Comment: In Column E add this formula `=IF(MID(D2,1,6)=A2,"Yes","No")` then sort on Column E and next Level sort on Column A

Comment: @MarcoGetrost If you look at the 1st line of the image that is actually what I want. however most of the other rows are wrong. I need row D and E to be in order with AB if 1st 6 numbers of GPI=THER_CLASS

Comment: @cyboashu Only 2 of the rows in all of the sheet are 'yes'. One of the GPI numbers from the bottom of the page could match with a THER_CLASS number on the top.

Comment: @DavidTunnell So basicly, for the second row, you would also want to have 011000 in column A and *Natural Penicillins** in Column B?

Comment: @MarcoGetrost Edit2:Column A and B are connected. Also, C & D are connected. I want each row to take the A column find which row the 1st 6 numbers of C column are equal and then move C and D to the row that A is on.

Comment: How will you deal with multiple matches though? Wouldn't it be better to do a vlookup in column E to match the Left(Key,6) against column A and copy the value in column B to E?

Comment: I'd suggest a **Pivot Table**! With a bit of tuning of the display, you should be able to do that! If you duplicate your source and modify the new a bit : `A=LEFT(C,6) | B=VLOOKUP(A;Old(A:B);2;FALSE) | C=Old(C) | D=Old(D)` then put all the fields in Row Fields (top to bottom : A to D) and play with display parameters to match your need! **Et voilà!** ;) *If I had your data, I'd have been faster to do than to explain it!^^*

Comment: @Flephal Sorry if I'm not being clear. If there are multiple THER)CLASS for a particular GPI just have multiple copies of it.

Comment: @r3uK here is the data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fm55PQhpN1vm3j57pD87hJvet-toHYpreIWpm1oKdPI/pubhtml

Comment: @davidtunnell : hehe, sorry I just left work and I'm communting!

Comment: As I see it; there are unique values in THER_CLASS while the keys can have multiple matches (The first 14 rows all match '011000'). As such this isn't something to sort. In another column you could add the code: =VLOOKUP(LEFT(C2,6),A:B,2,FALSE) and this should pull back the THER_CLASS_DESC that matches the key. This is different from what you are asking though. TBH - what you actually really want isn't that clear...

Comment: I see that you have some familiarity with SQL; you can think of VLookup kind of like a SELECT query. Instead of "SELECT [field] FROM [table] WHERE [primarykey] = [key]", you get "VLookup([key], [table], [index of field], False)" with the caveat that the leftmost column of [table] has to be the [primarykey] you're joining on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically just looking up the "Category" of each "Item". As Flephal points out, you can do this with VLookup.

1. Add a column E with the header "CLASS" and a column F with the header "CLASS_DESC".
2. For column E, starting with cell E2 and filling downwards, use the formula "=VLOOKUP(Left(C2, 6), A:B, 1, False)"
3. For column F, starting with cell F2 and filling downwards, use the formula "=VLOOKUP(Left(C2, 6), A:B, 2, False)"

Really, it would make much more sense if you didn't have the two tables mashed up next to one another and instead had each one on a different sheet. For example, move A & B to another sheet and call it "CLASSES".